# PHPBU executes no backups on localhost

Tags: php, backup

I have a XAMPP environment with PHP 7.0.
I installed PHPBU in my website project by putting the phpbu.phar and phpbu.xml files into the root directory.

My configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpbu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpbu.de/5.1/phpbu.xsd"
       verbose="true">
    <sync type="sftp">
        <option name="host" value="my-host"/>
        <option name="port" value="22"/>
        <option name="user" value="my-ftp-user"/>
        <option name="password" value="123456"/>
        <option name="path" value="/my/path"/>
        <option name="passive" value="true"/>
    </sync>
</phpbu>
```

I execute in my terminal:

```
php phpbu.phar
```

I get the following result:

```
phpbu 5.1.6 by Sebastian Feldmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.6
Configuration: C:\xampp\htdocs\www\european-business-ecademy\website\main\phpbu.xml

Time: 1 second, Memory: 4.00MB

No backups executed!
```

Nothing gets backuped. How come?

Answer (score 0):

From the configuration you have posted it doesn't seem that you are specifying what you want to backup.

Example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <phpbu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpbu.de/5.1/phpbu.xsd"
         verbose="true">
    <backups>
      <backup name="BackupDB">
        <!-- source -->
        <source type="mysqldump">
          <option name="databases" value="myDatabase"/>
          <option name="user" value="user.name"/>
          <option name="password" value="topsecret"/>
        </source>
        <!-- where should the backup be stored -->
        <target dirname="/path/to/backup/directory"
                filename="mysql-%Y%m%d-%H%i.sql"
                compress="bzip2"/>
    <!-- sync sftp -->
    <sync type="sftp">
      <option name="host" value="backup.example.com"/>
      <option name="port" value="22"/>
      <option name="user" value="user.name"/>
      <option name="password" value="topsecret"/>
      <option name="path" value="backup/someName"/>
      <option name="passive" value="true"/>
    </sync>
      </backup>
  </backups>
</phpbu>
```

The above will do a mysql backup and then it will transfer the backup file to a remote server via sftp.

You can check the documentation and an example of xml config:

```
http://phpbu.de/manual/current/en/configuration.html#configuration.xml
```